# Wordpress User Name Password Issue

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I am new in wordpress. I have set up my domain with wordpress all are working well. My site have added /wp-admin.php but when i am trying to login URL changed to /wp/wp-login.php and erroe message display.

Error is :

(Not Found

The requested URL /wp/wp-login.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.)

Please help as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your soonest reply brian. I have checked my cgi-bin directory Its empty. please guide me how to map cgi-bin directory?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, maybe you forgot one of the steps, for instance step 5: https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#Step_5:_Run_the_Install_Script

Comment: when i open this URL (mydomain.com/wp-admin/install.php) it gives me message like - Already Installed

You appear to have already installed WordPress. To reinstall please clear your old database tables first.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you installed the site at yoursite.com/wp/ and then moved it to yoursite.com

The config values are incorrect in the database.
You can correct if by using one of the fixes on this page
https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL